# How to get same width in material-ui card component?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

How to get these cards the same width?

[image]

When I'm using flexbox in material-ui for these cards width is not get the same size. How can I fix this? Should I use Grid for it? here are the card component and screen. flexbox I applied for the screen.

**card component**

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card'
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea'
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions'
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent'
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import { useStyles } from './classes'

const Post = ({card }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div>
    <Card className={classes.root}>    
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia className={classes.media}  image={card.selectedFile}/>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant='h5' component='h2'>
            {card.title}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant='body2' color='textSecondary' component='p'>
            {card.description}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>       
        <Button size='small' color='primary'>
          {card.category}
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  </div>
  )
}

export default Post
```

**card styles**

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
    margin: "3rem",    
    
  },
  media: {
    height: 140,
  },
}))
```

**screen**

```
import React from 'react'
import Post from '../components/card/Post'
import gallery from '../gallery'
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

const Posts = () => {
  return (
    <Box display="flex" flexWrap="wrap" justifyContent="center" m={1} p={1}>
      {gallery.map((card ,index) => (
        <Post key={index} card={card} />
      ))}
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Posts
```

Comment: Being first doesn't mean anything anymore I see, sad :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about add `minWidth` to root in **card styles**?

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
    minWidth: 100,
    margin: "3rem",    
    
  },
  media: {
    height: 140,
  },
}))
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it is possible because my react knowledge isn't that great, but maybe U can try setting a minWidth on the cards?

Or since u applied flex on the container, try applying

```
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
```

On the cards.

The `flex-basis` should set the base size of the cards to 0, normally this isnt the case.

The `flex-grow` will equally distribute the remaining size to the cards, but since normally the cards have a base sizes that is not 0 the distribution will look uneven.

Normally using those 2 css tags would fix problems like these. But like I said in the beginning, my knowledge of react isnt that great so I do not really know if this will work in react as well.

I hope this helps or at least pushes u in the right direction.